# Блокировка управления для игрока (GDScript)

Tags: функции, godot

Как **заблокировать** некоторые **функции** для игрока в момент нахождения **в воздухе**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавить проверку на нахождение на полу.

```
if is_on_floor():
    pass #заменить на функцию
```